# Is there a way to create two maps of arrays and access them based off of capitalization?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how I could test each character in a string to see if it is capital or not, and access the corresponding map of arrays.  I want to check each character in the userName variable, get if it's uppercase or lowercase, and access the value of the map that equals the letter.  Example: If I were to input "a", it would give me a random value from the fontmap and give me a random unicode character from fontmap[a]. Regular Javascript, I don't want to add any libraries, so please don't suggest that.

```js
function symbolGen() {
  var userName = document.getElementById("getName").value
  console.log(userName)
  var arrayOfSymbols = ['ڜ', 'ڠ', 'ʬ', 'Ώ', 'Θ', '⊗', '❁', '⁋', '©', '♲', 'Ω', '❉', '❋', '❃', '§', 'Ø', '※', '₴', '₿', '℣', '℗', '⅀', 'ψ', 'ↈ', '⟐', '➣', '❐', '♜', '❀', '❦', '❡', '☙', '☧', '☃', '☬', '☭', '♅', '♬', '☫', '☚', '☯', '☂', '◕', '▩', '☈', '░', '▓', '▚', '█', '␥', '⎙', '⎃', '␀', '⎗', '⎈', '⍼', '⍾', '⌘', '⌤', '⍨', '⍩', '⍢', '⍥', '⍤', '⌨', '⌫', '⌬', '⌱', '∝', '∮', '⇔', '↭', '↺', '﴿', '‽', '℘', '', '', '', 'Ⳃ', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'ᜈ', 'ꒌ', 'ꌲ', 'ㇱ', ' ᢆ', '៚', '៙', 'ᚙ', '፠', '࿈', '࿇', 'ඩ', 'ﷺ', '෴', '྿', '࿄', '࿃', '࿈', '࿉', '༗', '࿌', 'ᖰ', 'ᚏ', 'ᚘ', 'ᢁ', '', '', '', '', '', '☄', '✎', '〠', '₰', ''];

  function symbols() {
    var slider = document.getElementById("slider")
    var textToOutput = ""
    for (var i = 0; i < slider.value; i++) {
      textToOutput += arrayOfSymbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayOfSymbols.length)]
    }
    return textToOutput;
  }
  var finalText = symbols()
  var finalText2 = symbols()
  document.getElementById("generatedText").innerHTML = finalText + userName + finalText2
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(finalText + userName + finalText2)
}

function fontGen() {
  const fontMap = {
    a: ['æ', 'ɐ', 'ᴁ', '', '', '', 'ꪖ', '', 'ɑׁׅ֮', '', 'ᗋ', 'ᥲ', '', ''],
    b: ['ɓ', 'ƃ', 'ᴯ', 'ᴃ', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'ᗹ', '', '', '', ''],
    c: ['ƈ', 'ɔ', 'ɕ', '', '匚', '', '', '', 'ᘧ', 'ᝯׁ', '', 'Ꮸ', '', 'ℂ'],
    d: ['đ', 'ɖ', 'ɗ', 'ƌ', 'ð', 'ȡ', '', 'Ԃ', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
    e: ['ǝ', 'ɛ', 'ɘ', 'ɚ', '', 'Ⓔ', '', '', '', 'Ꮛ', 'ᥱ', '', ''],
    f: ['ƒ', 'ƭ', 'ɟ', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
    g: ['ǥ', 'ɠ', 'ƣ', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
    h: ['ƕ', 'ħ', '', '', '', 'ꫝ', '', '', '', 'ℋ'],
    i: ['ɨ', 'ı', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'ⅈ', '', ''],
    j: ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
    k: ['ƙ', 'ʞ', '', 'ⓚ', '', '', '', 'ᛕ', 'ƙׁׅ֑', 'Ꮶ'],
    l: ['ł', 'ƚ', '', 'ｌ', '', '', ''],
    m: ['ᵯ', '', 'ⓜ', '', '', '', 'ꪑ', 'ന', ''],
    n: ['ɲ', 'ƞ', 'ŋ', 'ᵰ', 'ռ', '', '', '', '', 'ꪀ'],
    o: ['œ', 'ø', 'ɵ', 'ȣ', 'ʊ', '', '', '', '', '០', 'ଠ', 'Ꮻ', '', ''],
    p: ['ƥ', 'ᵽ', '', '', '', 'ρ', '', '℘', 'ㄗ'],
    q: ['ƍ', '', '', '', ''],
    r: ['ᵲ', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
    s: ['ƨ', '', '', '', 'ᦓ', ''],
    t: ['ʈ', 'ŧ', '', '', '', '', '', 'ꪻ'],
    u: ['ᵾ', '', '', '', '', 'ᥩ'],
    v: ['ʋ', '', '', '', '', 'Ꮴ'],
    w: ['', '', '', '', '᭙', '', 'ᘺ', 'Ꮤ', 'ᜦ'],
    x: ['χ', '', '', '', '', 'ㄨ'],
    y: ['ƴ', 'ƛ', '', '', '', 'ꪗ', 'ㄐ'],
    z: ['ƶ', 'ȥ', '', '', 'ƺ'],
  }
  const upperCaseFontMap = {
    A: ['A'],
    B: [],
    C: [],
    D: [],
    E: [],
    F: [],
    G: [],
    H: [],
    I: [],
    J: [],
    K: [],
    L: [],
    M: [],
    N: [],
    P: [],
    Q: [],
    R: [],
    S: [],
    T: [],
    U: [],
    V: [],
    W: [],
    X: [],
    Y: [],
    Z: [],
  }
  const userName = document.getElementById("getName").value.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "")
  document.getElementById("generatedText")
  let customText = ''
  for (let i = 0; i < userName.length; i++) {
    if (/[a-z]/.test(userName[i]) == true) {
      const randomFontIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * fontMap[userName[i]].length)
      customText += fontMap[userName[i]][randomFontIndex]
    }
    if (/[A-Z]/.test(userName[i]) == true) {
      const randomFontIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * upperCaseFontMap[userName[i]].length)
      customText += upperCaseFontMap[userName[i]][randomFontIndex]
    }
    document.getElementById("generatedText").innerHTML = customText
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(customText)
  }
}
```

```css
.header {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  background-color: darkred;
  transition: 1s;
  top: 110px;
  left: 15px;
  position: absolute;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: red;
  transition: 1s;
}

.button2 {
  background-color: darkred;
  transition: 1s;
  top: 110px;
  left: 180px;
  position: absolute;
}

.button2:hover {
  background-color: red;
  transition: 1s;
}

.inputBox {
  background-color: lightblue;
  transition: 1s;
  font: bold;
  border-color: aqua;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 560px;
  left: 5px;
}

.inputBox:hover {
  transition: 1s;
  background-color: aqua;
  font: bold;
  border-color: lightblue;
}

.inputBox:active {
  animation: inputBoxAnimation 1ms infinite;
}

.generatedText {
  position: absolute;
  top: 170px;
  left: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 140px;
  left: 14px;
}

@keyframes inputBoxAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: skewX(20deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: skewY(20deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotateX(25deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotateY(-25deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(10deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

  <h1 class="header">
    Name picker for kahoots, etc
  </h1>
  <button class="button" type="button" id="button" onclick="symbolGen()">
Click for symbol gen
</button>
  <button class="button2" type="button" id="button2" onclick="fontGen()">
Click for fonts
</button>
  <input id="getName" class="inputBox" />
  <h3 id="generatedText" class="generatedText">
    The name will appear here!
  </h3>
  <div class="slider">
    <input type="range" id="slider" min="0" max="10" value="5">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `if (username[i] in fontMap)` and `if (username[i] in upperCaseFontMap)`

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have using regular expressions?

Comment: Additionally, why not have just one "fontmap" that contains upper-, and lower-, case characters?

Comment: The assignment to `innerHTML` and the clipboard should be after the end of the loop, not each time.

Comment: Use `else if` for mutually-exclusive conditions.

Comment: @DavidThomas I already tried that, it didn't work

Comment: Is there a problem with your code, it certainly seems to be working?

Answer (score 1):

I honestly don't see any need to a different solution or approach in your code.

I think it may not be working for you just because of this line:

```
const userName = document.getElementById("getName").value.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "")
```

You are converting to lowercase there, so any regex check for uppercase will not match after it. Just remove the conversion.

```
const userName = document.getElementById("getName").value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "")
```

```js
function symbolGen() {
  var userName = document.getElementById("getName").value
  console.log(userName)
  var arrayOfSymbols = ['ڜ', 'ڠ', 'ʬ', 'Ώ', 'Θ', '⊗', '❁', '⁋', '©', '♲', 'Ω', '❉', '❋', '❃', '§', 'Ø', '※', '₴', '₿', '℣', '℗', '⅀', 'ψ', 'ↈ', '⟐', '➣', '❐', '♜', '❀', '❦', '❡', '☙', '☧', '☃', '☬', '☭', '♅', '♬', '☫', '☚', '☯', '☂', '◕', '▩', '☈', '░', '▓', '▚', '█', '␥', '⎙', '⎃', '␀', '⎗', '⎈', '⍼', '⍾', '⌘', '⌤', '⍨', '⍩', '⍢', '⍥', '⍤', '⌨', '⌫', '⌬', '⌱', '∝', '∮', '⇔', '↭', '↺', '﴿', '‽', '℘', '', '', '', 'Ⳃ', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'ᜈ', 'ꒌ', 'ꌲ', 'ㇱ', ' ᢆ', '៚', '៙', 'ᚙ', '፠', '࿈', '࿇', 'ඩ', 'ﷺ', '෴', '྿', '࿄', '࿃', '࿈', '࿉', '༗', '࿌', 'ᖰ', 'ᚏ', 'ᚘ', 'ᢁ', '', '', '', '', '', '☄', '✎', '〠', '₰', ''];

  function symbols() {
    var slider = document.getElementById("slider")
    var textToOutput = ""
    for (var i = 0; i < slider.value; i++) {
      textToOutput += arrayOfSymbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayOfSymbols.length)]
    }
    return textToOutput;
  }
  var finalText = symbols()
  var finalText2 = symbols()
  document.getElementById("generatedText").innerHTML = finalText + userName + finalText2
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(finalText + userName + finalText2)
}

function fontGen() {
  const fontMap = {
    a: ['æ', 'ɐ', 'ᴁ', '', '', '', 'ꪖ', '', 'ɑׁׅ֮', '', 'ᗋ', 'ᥲ', '', ''],
    b: ['ɓ', 'ƃ', 'ᴯ', 'ᴃ', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'ᗹ', '', '', '', ''],
    c: ['ƈ', 'ɔ', 'ɕ', '', '匚', '', '', '', 'ᘧ', 'ᝯׁ', '', 'Ꮸ', '', 'ℂ'],
    d: ['đ', 'ɖ', 'ɗ', 'ƌ', 'ð', 'ȡ', '', 'Ԃ', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
    e: ['ǝ', 'ɛ', 'ɘ', 'ɚ', '', 'Ⓔ', '', '', '', 'Ꮛ', 'ᥱ', '', ''],
    f: ['ƒ', 'ƭ', 'ɟ', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
    g: ['ǥ', 'ɠ', 'ƣ', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
    h: ['ƕ', 'ħ', '', '', '', 'ꫝ', '', '', '', 'ℋ'],
    i: ['ɨ', 'ı', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'ⅈ', '', ''],
    j: ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
    k: ['ƙ', 'ʞ', '', 'ⓚ', '', '', '', 'ᛕ', 'ƙׁׅ֑', 'Ꮶ'],
    l: ['ł', 'ƚ', '', 'ｌ', '', '', ''],
    m: ['ᵯ', '', 'ⓜ', '', '', '', 'ꪑ', 'ന', ''],
    n: ['ɲ', 'ƞ', 'ŋ', 'ᵰ', 'ռ', '', '', '', '', 'ꪀ'],
    o: ['œ', 'ø', 'ɵ', 'ȣ', 'ʊ', '', '', '', '', '០', 'ଠ', 'Ꮻ', '', ''],
    p: ['ƥ', 'ᵽ', '', '', '', 'ρ', '', '℘', 'ㄗ'],
    q: ['ƍ', '', '', '', ''],
    r: ['ᵲ', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
    s: ['ƨ', '', '', '', 'ᦓ', ''],
    t: ['ʈ', 'ŧ', '', '', '', '', '', 'ꪻ'],
    u: ['ᵾ', '', '', '', '', 'ᥩ'],
    v: ['ʋ', '', '', '', '', 'Ꮴ'],
    w: ['', '', '', '', '᭙', '', 'ᘺ', 'Ꮤ', 'ᜦ'],
    x: ['χ', '', '', '', '', 'ㄨ'],
    y: ['ƴ', 'ƛ', '', '', '', 'ꪗ', 'ㄐ'],
    z: ['ƶ', 'ȥ', '', '', 'ƺ'],
  }
  const upperCaseFontMap = {
    A: ['A'],
    B: [],
    C: [],
    D: [],
    E: [],
    F: [],
    G: [],
    H: [],
    I: [],
    J: [],
    K: [],
    L: [],
    M: [],
    N: [],
    P: [],
    Q: [],
    R: [],
    S: [],
    T: [],
    U: [],
    V: [],
    W: [],
    X: [],
    Y: [],
    Z: [],
  }
  const userName = document.getElementById("getName").value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "")
  document.getElementById("generatedText")
  let customText = ''
  for (let i = 0; i < userName.length; i++) {
    if (/[a-z]/.test(userName[i]) == true) {
      const randomFontIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * fontMap[userName[i]].length)
      customText += fontMap[userName[i]][randomFontIndex]
    }
    if (/[A-Z]/.test(userName[i]) == true) {
      const randomFontIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * upperCaseFontMap[userName[i]].length)
      customText += upperCaseFontMap[userName[i]][randomFontIndex]
    }
    document.getElementById("generatedText").innerHTML = customText
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(customText)
  }
}
```

```css
.header {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  background-color: darkred;
  transition: 1s;
  top: 110px;
  left: 15px;
  position: absolute;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: red;
  transition: 1s;
}

.button2 {
  background-color: darkred;
  transition: 1s;
  top: 110px;
  left: 180px;
  position: absolute;
}

.button2:hover {
  background-color: red;
  transition: 1s;
}

.inputBox {
  background-color: lightblue;
  transition: 1s;
  font: bold;
  border-color: aqua;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 560px;
  left: 5px;
}

.inputBox:hover {
  transition: 1s;
  background-color: aqua;
  font: bold;
  border-color: lightblue;
}

.inputBox:active {
  animation: inputBoxAnimation 1ms infinite;
}

.generatedText {
  position: absolute;
  top: 170px;
  left: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 140px;
  left: 14px;
}

@keyframes inputBoxAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: skewX(20deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: skewY(20deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotateX(25deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotateY(-25deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(10deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

  <h1 class="header">
    Name picker for kahoots, etc
  </h1>
  <button class="button" type="button" id="button" onclick="symbolGen()">
Click for symbol gen
</button>
  <button class="button2" type="button" id="button2" onclick="fontGen()">
Click for fonts
</button>
  <input id="getName" class="inputBox" />
  <h3 id="generatedText" class="generatedText">
    The name will appear here!
  </h3>
  <div class="slider">
    <input type="range" id="slider" min="0" max="10" value="5">
  </div>
</body>
```